# Equation of one variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, factoring

> Solve the following equation.
>   $$(8-x)\cdot(x^2-2x+16)^2+2x^4\cdot(x^2-2x+16)=16x^7,$$
>   where $x\in \mathbb{R}$

I already know that we need to prove $x=2$, but don't know how to show it...
I'd be grateful for some hints or solutions ;)

Comment: Clara, where did you get the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It's $$(x-2)(16x^6+30x^5+65x^4+86x^3+240x^2+128x+1024)=0$$
and since
$$16x^6+30x^5+65x^4+86x^3+240x^2+128x+1024=$$
$$=(16x^6+30x^5+15x^4)+(50x^4+86x^3+37x^2)+(203x^2+128x+1024)>0,$$
we get the answer: $\{2\}$.

Comment: Oh, come on! Give us something human.

Comment: @john nobody I make it by hand (by "pencil and paper"). I am ready to explain (it's very ugly, but I am ready).

Comment: No need, I believe you. Is every bracket positive?

Comment: @john nobody Yes! They are non-negatives.  Just $\Delta<0$.

Comment: @johnnobody I did different from Rozenberg. I did it with finger and computer and got this pretty robotic  identity $$16 x^6+30 x^5+65 x^4+86 x^3+240 x^2+128 x+1024=\left(4 x^3+\frac{15 x^2}{4}+\frac{815 x}{128}+\frac{9791}{2048}\right)^2+\left(\frac{85 \sqrt{371} x}{128}+\frac{73929 \sqrt{\frac{7}{53}}}{10240}\right)^2+\frac{1381388452647}{1389363200}$$

Answer (score 0):

hint: your equation can be written as $$- \left( x-2 \right)  \left( 16\,{x}^{6}+30\,{x}^{5}+65\,{x}^{4}+86\,{
x}^{3}+240\,{x}^{2}+128\,x+1024 \right) 
=0$$

Comment: Still need to show that $x = 2$ is the only solution.

Comment: Show that $$16x^6+30x^5+65x^4+86x^3+240x^2+128x+1024>1005$$

Comment: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/fhjxat6spr